# Cookie policy in htmlunit

Tags: java, cookies, htmlunit

How do you specify a cookie policy in htmlunit to accept all cookies?

Comment: @Mat Banik, I post some answer, but it isn't really good.

Comment: I have found that rather than tweaking the cookie policy, it is better to see why the cookies are rejected - and fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just recreate the whole CookieManager class:
Here is source of the class: http://jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sourceforge/htmlunit/htmlunit/2.8/htmlunit-2.8-sources.jar!/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/CookieManager.java?format=ok

Now lookup this method `public synchronized Set<Cookie> getCookies(final URL url)`
in there you find this:

```
   public static final String HTMLUNIT_COOKIE_POLICY = CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY; //default
   final CookieSpec spec = registry_.getCookieSpec(HTMLUNIT_COOKIE_POLICY);

   for (final org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie cookie : all) {
        if (spec.match(cookie, cookieOrigin)) {
            matches.add(cookie);
        }
    }
```

Remote the specs matching statement `if (spec.match(cookie, cookieOrigin))` you you should accept all cookies regardless on policy. And/or you can work up ACCEPT_ALL_COOKIES flag and by pass the specs matching if that is the policy indicated in the configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Some solutions with source code modifications.

1. You can simply remove `cookieSpec.validate(cookie, cookieOrigin);` line from `org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies` in httpClient
2. In htmlUnit you can create your own strategy and use it in `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager` instead of

   ```
     public static final String HTMLUNIT_COOKIE_POLICY = CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY;
     ...
     final CookieSpec spec = registry_.getCookieSpec(HTMLUNIT_COOKIE_POLICY);
   ```

   Optionally it should depends from constructor parameter of CookieManager but authors doesn't think so)

   ```
    /**
     * HtmlUnit's cookie policy is to be browser-compatible. Code which requires access to
     * HtmlUnit's cookie policy should use this constant, rather than making assumptions and using
     * one of the HttpClient {@link CookiePolicy} constants directly.
     */
   ```

   So if you want implement your own Cookie strategy or deal with cases where `CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY` isn't  browser capability you should modify code.