# HTMLUnit and handling cookies ("WARNING: Cookie rejected")

Tags: wordpress, cookies, httpclient, htmlunit

I'm looking for a way to accept cookies (all cookies) using HTMLUnit

I'm trying to login to my wordpress site using HTMLUnit but I can't submit the form (and therefor can not login) when the cookies are rejected as my error is:

> Jul 14, 2012 10:42:24 PM
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies
>   WARNING: Cookie rejected:

CODE:

```
package backend;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Set;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.CookieManager;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie;

public class temp {

    WebClient myClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3);
    CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
    HtmlPage page;

    public void Someting() throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException{

    //Disabling Javascript for now.
    myClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    myClient.setCssEnabled(false);
    myClient.setCookieManager(cm);

    page = myClient.getPage("http://nick.wordpress.com/wp-admin");

    Set<Cookie> cookies = myClient.getCookieManager().getCookies();

    System.out.println("Page status code: " + page.getWebResponse().getStatusCode() + "\nPage status message: "  + page.getWebResponse().getStatusMessage());

    if(cookies != null)
    {
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies)
        {
            this.myClient.getCookieManager().addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("We have: " + myClient.getCookieManager().getCookies().size() + " cookie");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException{
        temp t = new temp();
        t.Someting();
    }
}
```

This code is excluding the WordPress form filling/submitting function as this doesn't seem relevant.

When searching the web I could only find 1 or 2 vague answers where I should modify the `"http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies"` class but I hope it can be done without this.

Comment: Maybe this discussion will help. Htmlunit might not expose the concerned configuration though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459279/httpclient-warning-cookie-rejected-illegal-domain-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681772/cookie-policy-in-htmlunit)

You have to recreate the  CookieManager class. 
Find the method `public synchronized Set<Cookie> getCookies(final URL url)` and remove the statement `if (spec.match(cookie, cookieOrigin))`.